# Accessing all the datasets of stored procedure with more than one (set of result) in Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a stored procedure in mysql database with has 4 select statements (datasets) but when I access it I am only getting the first row of the first select statement; in Mysql all the dataset are seen.

Here is what I did in Yii2:

```
$commande = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("call void()");
$result = $commande->queryAll();
//$result is only containing the first row of the first select statement
```

How can I get all the rest of dataset data?

Answer (score 0):

You should use query and nextResult

```
$commande = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("call void()");
$resultSet =  $commande->query();

   echo $resultSet->getRowCount();

 while( $resultSet->nextResult() !== false ) {
   ....... your code ....
  };
```